# collapsing rows in a data frame while merging another column value

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, plyr, reshape2

I have this data sets

```
d1 = data.frame(PatID=c(1,1,1,2,2,4,1,2), 
                code1=c(1,2,3,1,2,7,2,8), 
                location=c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'))
```

I want to eliminate duplicate rows (on `PatID`) so

1. I get only one row for each unique `PatID`;
2. merge values for code1 for all common rows,
3. retain location for any one matching row (for first or last row - does not matter).

Output should be:

```
PatID    code1    location 
1        1,2,3    a 
2        1,2,8    d 
4        7        f
```

I have tried unsuccessfully aggregate, ddply and even struggled with melt dcast. I am a former unix programmer but new to [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Answer (score 4):

`ddply` works just fine:

```
ddply(d1,.(PatID),
      summarise,
      code1 = paste(unique(code1),collapse = ','),
      location = location[1])

  PatID code1 location
1     1 1,2,3        a
2     2 1,2,8        d
3     4     7        f
```

Oh fine. Here's the data.table version:

```
d2 <- as.data.table(d1)
> d2[,list(code1 = paste(unique(code1),collapse = ','),location = location[1]),by = 'PatID']
   PatID code1 location
1:     1 1,2,3        a
2:     2 1,2,8        d
3:     4     7        f
```

Comment: While you're at it, you should add the obligatory `data.table` approach too :)

Comment: for `data.table` (and maybe `plyr` too, I don't know), keep it as a list, instead of pasting imo, i.e. `... code1 = list(unique(code1)) ...`

Comment: And base R's `aggregate`? C'mon? Where's the spirit in this answer? :) Oh fine. +1.

Comment: @eddi, lists in `data.frame`/`data.table` columns seems to confuse ***some*** people, especially when they try to use `write.csv` with it. But for analysis, I totally agree with your comment.

Comment: Wow!!! Jorans solution worked elegantly and perfectly. I was going to check back by evening, hoping I will have a response or two. Within seconds I have a solution. You all are awesome!!!  Thanks so mcuh Joran and Ananda for lively interaction above as well.

Comment: @joran, why do you say `by` makes more sense than `aggregate`. I can't actually think of a convenient way to apply different functions to different variables when "aggregating" in some way (`tapply`, `by`, `aggregate`...) other than these two and maybe `sqldf` if you know sql. I was mostly pulling your leg, but now your comment leaves me wondering if I'm missing out on something!

Comment: I would be curious to see a by or aggregate solution, problem is solved but just for learning and future

Comment: @snigs, I posted an `aggregate` solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17707931/1270695) though it also depends on `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure base R isn't entirely ignored (or to make you appreciate the syntax of "plyr" and "data.table" for these types of problems)...

Two options:

#### Option 1: Use `ave` to do the "aggregation" and `unique` to slim down the output

```
unique(within(d1, {
  code1 <- ave(code1, PatID, 
               FUN=function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ","))
  location <- ave(location, PatID, FUN=function(x) x[1])
}))
#   PatID code1 location
# 1     1 1,2,3        a
# 4     2 1,2,8        d
# 6     4     7        f
```

#### Option 2: Get `aggregate` and `merge` working together

```
merge(
  aggregate(code1 ~ PatID, d1, 
          function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ",")),
  aggregate(location ~ PatID, d1, function(x) x[1]))
#   PatID code1 location
# 1     1 1,2,3        a
# 2     2 1,2,8        d
# 3     4     7        f
```

---

The closest purely `aggregate` solution I can think of is as follows:

```
aggregate(cbind(code1, as.character(location)) ~ PatID, d1, 
          function(x) cbind(paste(unique(x), collapse = ","),
                            as.character(x[1])))
#   PatID code1.1 code1.2    V2.1 V2.2
# 1     1   1,2,3       1 a,b,c,g    a
# 2     2   1,2,8       1   d,e,h    d
# 3     4       7       7       f    f
```

It gives you all the information you were interested in, and a decent amount of information you weren't interested in too...